# Add invitees to Events in Apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

How can I add invitees(attendees) to salesforce events in an apex test class method?

Comment: Just posting one liner sentence is not enough. Share your code which you tried so that community can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Event Relation object. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) states

> This object lets you add or remove invitees from an event and use the API to manage invitees’ responses to invitations.

**Code**

```
EventRelation er = new EventRelation(EventId = '00UD0000005zijH', 
    RelationId = '003D000000Q8adV');
insert er;
```